# How to get 'cancel' button to continue redirect in enhanced auth dialog?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, authentication

Our app is configured as a "website" within Facebook, and we have authenticated referrals turned on.

Our goal is to have everyone authenticated by default if they click through one of our stories.  However, if they do not authorize they app we **still want them to proceed to our app**, just not authenticated.  Both Viddy and SocialCam seem to take this approach at the moment.

We're having a hard time getting this working.

Currently, when users click one of our timeline stories they get an enhanced auth dialog in a pop-up display, with the option to proceed or "Close".  Selecting  the 'close' button just cancels the referral.  You can see the type of dialog we're viewing under the "authenticated referrals" heading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

We'd like to see the enhanced auth dialog open in a full page (not a pop-up), and present the user with a 'cancel' button that if clicked still refers the user to the URL, but does not authenticate them.  The first screenshot on this page is the type of auth dialog we want to see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

How do we get an enhanced auth dialog with a 'cancel' button (that continue redirect) as opposed to the 'close' button that does not?

Do we need to turn off authenticated referrals and make this happen through some other means?

Should our app be configured as something different than a 'website' in app settings?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With authenticated referrals, cancel always sends you back to the newsfeed, or wherever you came from in Facebook. This cannot be changed.

However, whenever you instantiate the auth dialog yourself (FB.login, /dialog/oauth etc) then the cancel button works as before, it sends the user to the redirect URI you supplied.

So, if you want the behaviour you suggest, you need to disable authenticated referrals and redurect the user to /dialog/oauth which will display the full page auth dialog. Clicking 'cancel' here will still take the user to your redirect URI.